# Find all matches of a pattern and replace them in a text

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a pattern as below:

```
measurement = re.compile("(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*(cm|mm|millimeter|centimeter|millimeters|centimeters)")
```

It can be seen in several times in a sentence and in a document. I want to find all matches and replace it with "MEASUREMENT", also I want to add its value in a list.

```
**Input_Text**: measuring 9 x 5 mm and previously measuring 8 x 6 mm

**Output**: measuring MEASUREMENT and previously measuring MEASUREMENT

**List**: 9 x 5 mm, 8 x 6 mm
```

So far my code is below but it only brings the first match:

```
result = re.search(measurement, Input_Text)
                    if result:
                        Input_Text = Input_Text.replace(result, "MEASUREMENT")
```

Comment: use `re.finditer(pattern, string)` ;).

Comment: You can't replace `result` in text, anyway; it's a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Comment: So why is there a separate `findings_section` variable? Is that the same thing as `Input_Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) for the replacement, and `re.findall()` to get all matched strings.

```python
measurement = re.compile("(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*(cm|mm|millimeter|centimeter|millimeters|centimeters)")

text = "measuring 9 x 5 mm and previously measuring 8 x 6 mm"

values = re.findall(pattern=measurement, string=text)

sub_text = re.sub(pattern=measurement, string=text, repl='MEASUREMENT')

>>> sub_text
'measuring MEASUREMENT and previously measuring MEASUREMENT'

>>> values
[('9', '5', 'mm'), ('8', '6', 'mm')]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to parse your string twice, you can use `re.sub` with a function as replacement parameter. With this function you can easily populate a list of matching strings.

```
pat = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?\s*x\s*\d+(?:\.\d*)?\s*(?:cm|mm|millimeters?|centimeters?)')

s = r'measuring 9 x 5 mm and previously measuring 8 x 6 mm'

l = []

def repl(m):
    l.append(m.group(0))
    return 'MEASUREMENT'

s = pat.sub(repl, s)
```

Comment: Coming from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935066/substitute-regular-expression-and-get-list-of-matches?noredirect=1#comment114803347_64935066
It worked for me.